# Opencv imshow is right whereas imwrite is wrong?

Tags: python, opencv

I just want to cover an png image with another png image, `cv2.imshow` got the right result, `cv2.imwrite` got the strange result.

```
coverImg = cv2.imread('./images/cover.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
back = cv2.imread('./images/back.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

x_offset = y_offset = 0

y1, y2 = y_offset, y_offset + coverImg.shape[0]
x1, x2 = x_offset, x_offset + coverImg.shape[1]

alpha_s = coverImg[:, :, 3] / 255.0
alpha_l = 1.0 - alpha_s

result = back.copy()

for c in range(0, 3):
    result[y1:y2, x1:x2, c] = (alpha_s * coverImg[y1:y2, x1:x2, c] +
                               alpha_l * result[y1:y2, x1:x2, c])

cv2.imshow("result", result)
res2 = cv2.imwrite("./result.png", result)
```

`result.dtype` is `uint8`

imshow:
[image: imshow result]

imwrite:
[image]

my back.png
[image: back.png]

my cover.png
[image: cover.png]

Comment: Watch the data types... are you sure you are writing a **BGR 8-bit unsigned integer** image?

Comment: `imshow()` doesn't understand transparency and renders transparent regions as black IIRC. I'm suggesting your image has lots of transparent regions.

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes, it has lots of transparent regions, I just wonder why `imwrite` got a strange image..

Comment: Try splitting your image into its 4 constituent channels with `cv2.split()` and then stacking the resulting 4 BGRA channels across the page with `np.hstack()` and saving the result so you can see all 4 channels side-by-side.

Comment: Provide a proper [mcve], including both input images, that will allow us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @DanMašek I have uploaded my input images.

Comment: Your `result` is a copy of `back`, which is BGRA. You overwrite the colour channels, but leave the transparency as it was originally. Since pretty much everything is transparent in the background image, other than the shadows, you don't see anything in the output image (although the colours are still there in the data). Since `imshow` ignores transparency, you see it all in there.

Comment: Assuming you want the result to still have transparency, you will need to combine the alpha channels as well. A very simple approach would be: For each pixel, select the larger of the two alpha values (since 255 means opaque). e.g. `result[:,:,3] = np.maximum(coverImg[:,:,3], back[:,:,3])`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem occurs because you're modifying a copy of the original background image, which you loaded as BGRA, but do not modify the alpha channel on the result. Since the background image is mostly transparent (other than the shadows), so is the result when viewed by something that supports alpha.

To fix this and keep the result partially transparent (where appropriate), you need to merge the alpha channels as well. Since `alpha=0` means fully transparent, `alpha=255` means fully opaque, and our goal is to retain the opaque parts of both images, let's take `max(foreground_alpha, background_alpha)` for each pixel. This can be accomplished using [`np.maximum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html):

```
result[y1:y2, x1:x2, 3] = np.maximum(coverImg[y1:y2, x1:x2, 3], back[y1:y2, x1:x2, 3])
```

---

The full script (with added imports and call to `cv2.waitKey`):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

coverImg = cv2.imread('front.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
back = cv2.imread('back.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

x_offset = y_offset = 0

y1, y2 = y_offset, y_offset + coverImg.shape[0]
x1, x2 = x_offset, x_offset + coverImg.shape[1]

alpha_s = coverImg[:, :, 3] / 255.0
alpha_l = 1.0 - alpha_s

result = back.copy()

for c in range(0, 3):
    result[y1:y2, x1:x2, c] = (alpha_s * coverImg[y1:y2, x1:x2, c] +
                               alpha_l * result[y1:y2, x1:x2, c])

result[y1:y2, x1:x2, 3] = np.maximum(coverImg[y1:y2, x1:x2, 3], back[y1:y2, x1:x2, 3])

cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey()
res2 = cv2.imwrite("result.png", result)
```

This produces:

[image: Output image]